# postgresql - start on mac - `pg_ctl` not working

Tags: database, postgresql, shell, command-line

I want to use the pre-installed postgresql on my local machine (mac os 10.7.5), when I run `which psql` I find it (in `/usr/bin/psql`), but then running

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/bin/psql -l /usr/bin/psql/server.log start
```

results in:

```
-bash: pg_ctl: command not found
```

How can I start/use my postgresql database? do I need to install it (with say Homebrew) or can I use the pre-installed one on my mac?
I also tried using the `initdb` command (`initdb /usr/bin/psql -E utf8`) and also go tthe same message: `-bash: initdb: command not found`.

Also, is this `psql` the same as `postgres`? (I tried `which postgres` and got nothing)

Update: I'm using `psql` commands in the command line, but am getting there the following message (for `psql -l` and `psql -a` for instance):

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Comment: Thank god this question wasn't deleted. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OS X ships with the command line client (for interacting with postgres databases) not the server.

You need to install the server.

Check [the postgres site](http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/) or grab the [postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/)

Comment: Thank you, I tried postgerapp now, and updated the path in the `.zshrc` file, but am still getting the same error: `psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

Comment: I ended up using homebrew to install postgres itself