# psql -h localhost won't connect on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, postgresql, postgresapp

Per Postgresapp.com

> psql is the PostgreSQL command-line interface to your database. Mac OS 10.7 ships with an older version of PostgreSQL, which can be started with the following command:
>
> $ psql -h localhost

So I run `psql -h localhost` and get

```
Dans-MacBook-Pro:~ djechlin$ psql -h localhost
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

As far as I can tell `psql` is simply client side, and Postgresapp.com's documentation is talking smack. I still have no idea how to start a postgres server locally and haven't been able to find any documentation on that.

Version:

```
Dans-MacBook-Pro:~ djechlin$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.1.5
contains support for command-line editing
```

I'm on Mac 10.8.4.

Answer (score 1):

This was admittedly more confusing than it should have been, but...

- `pg_ctl` is the command usually responsible for starting the postgres server. [OS X does not come bundled with it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16119174/1339987). How to run it is [explained in this pre-Postgres.app answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7975660/1339987).
- When you install Postgres.app and run it, it starts the server, so you don't have to manage it. That's the added value of Postgres.app if you already have the client-side tools installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to postgres user and open psql prompt

```
 sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```

From here you can create more *roles, databases, etc* and connect to what you created from whatever you're trying to connect from.

Here is a useful cheat-sheet of commands I have often referred to:

```
 http://blog.jasonmeridth.com/posts/postgresql-command-line-cheat-sheet/
```